# R function to identify if result is an integer from round()

Tags: r, loops, integer

I am trying to solve the following query:

Using a loop, create a new vector the same length as v1, that contains the value TRUE if the corresponding element of v1 has an integer square root and the value FALSE otherwise.
I have currently created the below but cant get the correct output.

```
v4 <- sqrt(v1)
v4 <- round(v4,1)

for (i in seq(v4))
{
 if (i%%1==0) {print ("TRUE")}
 else {print ("FALSE")}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop for that because R can do vectorized calculations. So if you have a vector with several elements and you want to performa operation on each of these elements (here: calculating the square root and checking if the sqrt is an integer), you can directly do so.

NoteI: the code below assumes that there is an input vector v1 with several elements.
Note II: your code above wouldn't work, because you are overriding the assignment `v4 <- sqrt(v1)` with the rounded result in the next line.
Note III: in your post you mention that you want to get a new vector (which my code below does), although cor code suggest to simply print the results into the console.

```
v1 <- 1:25
v1_sqrt <- sqrt(v1)         

v2 <- v1_sqrt == round(v1_sqrt, 0)
v2
```

which gives:

```
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

EDIT. since the TO wants a loop, here's a solution:

```
v1 <- 1:25
v1_sqrt <- sqrt(v1)

v2 <- NULL

for (i in 1:length(v1_sqrt))
{
  v2[i] <- v1_sqrt[i] == round(v1_sqrt[i], 0)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - for this task I specifically have to complete the task using a loop unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

If you *have* to use loop you can do :

```
v4 <- 1:10
answer <- logical(length(v4))

for (i in seq_along(v4)) {
  answer[i] <- sqrt(v4[i]) %% 1 == 0
}

answer
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```